# Jquery Select only one Image from list

Tags: jquery, css

Want to select only one image at a time from this below jsbin link code

http://jsbin.com/avaxay/1/edit

Code:

```
$(function() {

  $("img").click(function() {

    $("img").not(this).removeClass("hover");

    $(this).toggleClass("hover");

  });

  $("#btn").click(function() {

    var imgs = $("img.hover").length;    
    alert('there are ' + imgs + ' images selected');

  });

});
```

Thanks....

Comment: Which one ?? the last clicked one ?

Comment: yes allow only 1 image to select here its selecting multiple

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
  $("img").click(function() {

    $("img").not(this).removeClass("hover");

    $(this).toggleClass("hover");

  });
```

it removes the `hover` class from all images (except the current removed with the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method) and toggle the class for the current.

Updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/avaxay/36/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("img").click(function() {

    $('ul > li > img').removeClass("hover);
    $(this).addClass("hover");

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $("img.hover").attr('class', '');
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");

  });
```

I hope this is what you expected

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function or [jQuery.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

I think the best solution here could be the use of `jQuery.off('click')`

```
$("img").click(function(){
   $("img").off('click');
});
```

and then, re-enable when the alert is triggered

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c7puz/

### JS

```
// function to do something when the click is trigger
function enableSelect(){
    $("img").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("hover");
      // toggle off the click, so only first one will work,
      // until the function is called again
      $("img").off('click');
    });
}enableSelect();

$("#btn").click(function(){
    var pos = $("img.hover").parent().index();
    if(pos > -1){
        // tell us the selected image to work with
        alert('The selected image is at position: ' + pos );
        // clear the hover state
        $("img").removeClass("hover");
        // and enable the click again
        enableSelect();
    } else {
        alert('no image selected');
    }
});
```

Good luck ;-)